# View Data that is filtered out by WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, filter, view

I have a simple SQL query that filters out data in the WHERE clause. Is it possible to view the records that were filtered out? The goal is to view the filtered data along with a a new self-defined column that displays the Filter reason.

Ex: I want to filter out products that have been discontinued, i would want to display the records that are filtered along with a new column "Filter Reason", that would say "Discontinued" for these specific records.

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be looking for a LEFT JOIN... Anyway you need to show us your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS Access, you would use `iif()` if you wanted both filtered and unfiltered records:

```
select t.*,
       iif(<filter condition>, "", "Discontinued") as filter_reason
from t
```

Comment: And what if i had multiple iif statements but with only one "filter_reason" Column

Comment: @Manny . . . I don't understand.  You don't need multiple `iif()`s unless you have multiple filters.   Perhaps you should ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I will have multiple filters but with only one filter_reason column indicating the reason it was filtered, if that makes any sense.

Comment: @Manny . . . Ask a *new* question with a better description of the data and the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 more column like this:

```
SELECT *, 'Discontinued' AS [Filter Reason]
FROM products
WHERE (column = something)
```

`column = something` is the condition to check if the product is discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both rows filtered and rows left out, WHERE is probably not what you are looking for, try sorting instead:

```
SELECT  [Condition] -- this is the column containing condition to check
              -- other  colums go here
         ,CASE
             WHEN [Condition]='Your_Condition' THEN 'condition_met'
             ELSE 'condition_unmet' 
         END as 'COND'
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY 'COND'
```